# py2app error on launch after App download

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I created a python application on my macOS Big Sur 11.6 ,  bundling my python code with `py2app` and all works fine. I can run it with a double click all goes smooth.

Now I want to share it with friends and other people so I uploaded it on `Google Drive` ( I haven't zipped it before uploading, maybe this could be an error) and downloaded it again, tested and all fine.

Now I shared the link with some friends, they downloaded the app but aren't able to launch it. They opened the app with `ctrl` to avoid "developer not identified" but an unexpected problem appeared :[image: Launch error]

They are not developers, I don't know if they have python3 installed but for sure they don't have `py2app` on their Macs.  I could create a python/sh script to download some libraries. For me debugging is hard, since the error is very generic and on my machine all goes smooth.

To bundle the application I followed this tutorial on official docs :https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html just for the last step I used "python3" not "python" because it couldn't write on directory `/dist/MyApp.app` but I saw this is a common problem fixable as I did.

Do you have any ideas?